# Query unexpectedly fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a simple member system using MySQL, and have stumbled onto a problem.
The issue is that I am using the correct SQL query to search the column `Username`, and find `Administrator`, but however my query isn't finding anything.

I have searched the internet for a solution (with many results taking my back to Stack Overflow), but however have not found anything.

The query that I am using is:

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE Username = "Administrator"
```

Which looks find from my end, but however does not return any results:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here?
I am new to MySQL & PHP, so if something is obviously wrong with what I'm doing here, please tell me nicely, and please don't 'flame'.

**Edit:**

When attempting to run this query though PHP, I get:

`Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/crysisor/public_html/checklogin.php on line 22`

The above code confirms that something is wrong...
Relevant code:

```
$user = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqli, $_POST['user']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($sqli, $_POST['pass']);
     if ($user && $pass) {

      $checkuser= mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($sqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='".$user."'"));
```

Comment: Are you sure that there actually is data in the table? There is no problem with your syntax.

Comment: Can you post the result of `select distinct username from members`?

Comment: @Rahul The query comes back empty.

Comment: That means your table members has no data and so your query return empty result.

Comment: @Rahul Strange, but the table has one row, populated with the user 'Administrator', and the respective information. Is this something that can easily be fixed?

Comment: Post the result of `SELECT * FROM members`

Comment: I get: 'Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0001 sec)', which doesn't make sense since the 'Administrator' user and respective information is in the `members` table.

Comment: Refresh your browser **completely**

Comment: @RyanVincent Just did that, and it's still a no-go.

Comment: How do you know the row is in the table? Are you using a separate application? I use an 'SQL' 'workbench' or equivalent.

Comment: Screen print you have posted shows the row? from where you don't see the row? from your app? or where?

Comment: @Rahul I was first attempting to see if the table existed using MySQLi and PHP, and this database query failed. The same query also does not work from within PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: Not really sure but try relogin again and see.

Comment: @Rahul I know this could sound extreme, but could it potentially be an issue with my hosting provider? I've had issues with their caching systems before, and they're supposed to be turned off right now (I requested it to be turned off for my site).

Comment: May be but can't say for sure.

Comment: @Rahul Well, my PHPMyAdmin just crashed out on me. I'll contact my hosting provider (they normally reply to tickets within 5 minutes or so), and hope for the best :).

Comment: Your edit suggests that the problem is with your calling PHP code and not the query itself. Can you post the relevant snippet from `checklogin.php`?

Comment: You are using different table names in the PHP code and in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: @EdCottrell Issue resolved with MySQL. It was related to a typographic error in my PHP script and website HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few hints which may help you resolve your problem.

- Make the query itself a PHP variable, and echo it. Then copy and paste the echoed result into phpMyAdmin.
- Use single quotes for query variables. The query itself should be in double quotes.
- Unrelated: the password looks short. It shouldn't be stored in plain text.

Comment: Yeah, I'm planning to start encrypting it once I've got past this hurdle.

Comment: Update: It was actually a problem with the way I was forwarding the information from my form onto the PHP script. Thanks for hinting this (your first suggestion did it!).